# Javascript Form Submission Not Working. What could it be?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

The form won't submit

```css
button {
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}
p {
    font: 22px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;  
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #040607;
}
q {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    font: 24px Helvetica Bold, Arial, Sans-Serif; 
}
textarea {
    padding: 12px;
    font: 16px Helvetica Bold, Arial, Sans-Serif; 
    
    width: 300px;
    height: 120px;
}
.quote {
    top: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    
    width: 436px;
    height: 270px;
}

a {
    color: #FF9C00; 
}
button {
    color: #FFFFFF; 
    
    background: #FFAF30; 
    box-shadow: inset 0px 4px 8px #FF9C00;
    
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 16px;
    border-color: #FF9C00;
    
    padding: 3px;
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-right: 16px;
}
button, a{
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 1px;  
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #040607;
    
    font-weight: bold;
    font: 22px Monaco, Sans-Serif; 
}
fieldset{
    width: 436px;
    height: 270px;
    position: relative;

    line-height: 50px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    border-color: #040607;
    font: 22px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;  
}
footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px; 
    padding-top: 35px;
    
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: fixed;
 
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #0851A8;
    
    color: #FFFFFF; 
    font-weight: bold;
    font: 15px Monaco, Sans-Serif;

    background: #3780D8;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 10px 20px #0851A8;
    opacity: .95;
}
legend{
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 2px;  
    font: 30px Helvetica Bold, Arial, Sans-Serif; 
    
    color: #3780D8; 
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 1px #040607;
}
li{
    list-style-type: none;

    line-height: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    
    color: #040607; 
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #2E3845;
    font: 22px Helvetica Bold, Arial, Sans-Serif; 

    text-align: center;
}
textarea {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    resize: none;

    width: 270px;
    height: 166px;

    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;

    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px #040607;
}
q {
    display: block; 
    
    font-weight: bold;
    font: 26px Helvetica Bold, Arial, Sans-Serif; 
    
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    
    color: #040607; 
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #2E3845;
}
.content {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    
    width: 100%; 
    min-height: 100%;
    
    background: #FFFFFF; 
}
.left {
    left: 5%;
    top: 120px;
    float: left;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    
    width: 40%;
}
.right {
    right: 5%;
    top: 120px;
    float: right;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    
    width: 40%;
}
.italic {
    font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>SMPentest Challenge</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/final.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css" />
<script>
function validateForm() {
    alert("Submitted Successfully!");
    return true;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="quote">
            <q class="normal">Submit the form.</q>
            <q class="italic">Test</q>
            <q class="normal">Test</q>
            <q class="italic">Test</q>
            <q class="normal">Test</q>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class=right>
        <form method="POST" onsubmit="return validateForm();" action="#">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Contact Info</legend>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="name">name</label></td>
                        <td><input name="name" id="name" type="text" size="20" maxlength="30" required autocomplete="off" placeholder="Required"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="email">email</label></td>
                        <td><input name="email" id="email" type="text" size="20" maxlength="2" required autocomplete="off" placeholder="Required"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <p>Preferred Choice:</p>
                <div class=boxes>
                    <input name="summer" id="summer" type="checkbox"/>
                    <label for="summer">#1</label>
                    <br/>
                    <input name="winter" id="winter" type="checkbox"/>
                    <label for="winter">#2</label>
                    <br/>
                    <input name="fall" id="fall" type="checkbox"/>
                    <label for="fall">#3</label>
                    <br/>
                </div>
                <input name="i_know" type=hidden value="KungFu!"/>
                <button name="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<footer>Test Page</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any errors in console? Seems to be working for me.

Comment: I get an alert that says it's successful. What else are you expecting? If you mean that the form isn't being processed, then why are you using `action="#"`?

Comment: You might want to read [*How to create a **minimal**, complete and verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Often the process of creating the example will highlight your issue so you don't need to ask.

Comment: It works here: https://jsfiddle.net/498xmoxq/

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The action field should be set to where you want the form to be submitted to. It is currently set to nothing.

```
    action="#"
```

I would also advise against the use of inline Javascript, even for such a small function.

Comment: What is wrong with inline Javascript?, At least explain why you would recommend against it, rather than basing it on your recomendation with no factual evidence as to why?

Comment: Its not wrong for a testcase ... but to structre your applications its better to have a clean named files instaed of to much inline code  ..  .. also for 'dry' code ... so you can reuse your functions also in other html files and you can look into your 'js' folder into your 'formHandle.js' file into your validateXyForm function if you need to make changes